# How to access and print JavaScript object property values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, properties

I am trying to access the value of object property 'cols' and it throws undefined.
What's wrong with the code?

```
$(function() {

   $('body').dialog(function(input) {
      setTimeout(function() {
         console.log(input);
      }, 100);
   }, {
      cols: 40,
      rows: 20,
      message: 'Enter Name',
      title: 'Log Form'
   });

   $('.dialog').on('click', function() {
      console.log(this.cols)
   });
});
```

Comment: please add your matching html code

Comment: Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.